# issue using cloumnFilter on JQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to implement jquery datatables plug-in columnFilter 
(http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html).
it is working fine when using `type="text"` or `type="date-range"`. when using `type="select"` without specifiyng the values the function break. if I specify the values it works fine.
my values are text.

this is my html:

```
<table id="dataTable50-2">      
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>@Resources.LeadType</th>
            <th>@Resources.Provider</th>
            <th>@Resources.Campaigns_CampaignName</th>
            <th>@Resources.FirstName</th>
            <th>@Resources.LastName</th>
            <th>@Resources.Phone</th>
            <th>@Resources.Email</th>
            <th>@Resources.InsertionDate</th>
            <th>@Resources.InsertionTime</th>
            @if (ViewBag.Department != null)
            {
                <th>@Resources.LeadAttachedToUser</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>@Resources.LeadType</th>
            <th>@Resources.Provider</th>
            <th id="campaignCol">@Resources.Campaigns_CampaignName</th>
            <th>@Resources.FirstName</th>
            <th>@Resources.LastName</th>
            <th>@Resources.Phone</th>
            <th>@Resources.Email</th>
            <th>@Resources.InsertionDate</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var lead in Model)
        {
            counter++;
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@lead.LeadType.TypeDescription</td>
                <td>@lead.Campaign.Provider.ProviderName</td>
                <td>@lead.Campaign.CampaignName</td>
                <td>@lead.FirstName</td>
                <td>@lead.LastName</td>
                <td>@lead.MobilePhone</td>
                <td>@lead.Email</td>
                <td>@(((DateTime)lead.InsertionDateTime).ToShortDateString())</td>
                <td>@(((DateTime)lead.InsertionDateTime).ToShortTimeString())</td>
                @if (ViewBag.Department != null)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => lead.User.UserID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Users, "Value", "Text"), Resources.ChooseRepresentative, new { @class = "lead_User_UserID" })
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataTable50-2').dataTable({
        aaSorting: [],
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        bJQueryUI: true
    })
    .columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [
            null,
            { type: "text"},
            { type: "text"},
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "text"},
            { type: "text"},
            { type: "text"},
            { type: "select"},
            { type: "date-range" },
            null,
            null
        ]
    });
});
```

can anyone think of a reasone why I don't get the select to work?

thanks!

Comment: seems pretty obvious that it expects values to create the options

Comment: @charlietfl, try read what columnfilter is intended to do.

Comment: @Shlo, show us your code, how you initialize the table and the ColumnFilter.

Comment: @davidkonrad i added the code to my question. thanks.

Comment: It looks okay.  Assuming there actually is populated data, the select should be populated also. It is not good you can have mismatch in the number of columns between header, body and footer, dataTables dont like that at all. This could be the problem. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: after banging my head against the wall for some time, I decided to try another add-on. I tried: ["Yet Another DataTables Column Filter"](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/15016/yet-another-datatables-column-filter-yadcf) and it works perfect!